Destroying scheduled jobs from Solid Queue
I have a Rails app that allows users to sign up and add a list of friends or loved ones with their birthdays. The app will then email the user on their loved ones' birthdays (reminder).
To achieve this I am using Action Mailer (to send emails) and Active Job (for delivering at specified date & time) and the background job adapter I am using is the solid_queue.
I have successfully implemented this in both the development & production environments. The emails are sent to the user at midnight of their preferred time zone selected when the user created the account.
The solid queue enqueues the job whenever the user creates or updates the birthdate field. So, let's say I create a reminder birthday of a loved one, it triggers the solid queue and schedules it to be delivered later on their birthday.
But now, the problem is that when the user updates an existing birthdate field for any loved one, the solid queue will trigger again and create a new scheduled job to send an email on the updated birthday. So now we have 2 scheduled jobs in the db for a single birthday. (1st created at create and 2nd was created at update). And now 2 emails will be sent for a single loved one's birthday on different dates which is not what we want.
Currently, the only solution I can think of is that when the birthdate field is updated, we need to delete an existing job first and create another scheduled job for the updated birthdate.
But how should I, or putting it this way, what's the best way to query the solid queue db for a particular instance and delete it from the scheduled jobs?
Or is there a much better way that the Solid Queue offers that I am not aware of?
Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated! :)

Did you ever figure this out or get an answer?

Yes, Before sending the email, I added an if clause to whether it's being sent on the right date...if Date.today == birthday_buddy.birthday

Great. I was looking for a solution to a similar problem. @JuzerShakir what you suggest is the best.

Since you didn't include a code example and depending on your implementation, you can capture the job_id when the job is created (retrievable by appending .job_id to the job object).
Later, you can use it to find and discard the existing job as follows:
SolidQueue::Job.find_by(active_job_id: job_id).discard

